# simple php form send attachment no mime/libraries

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments

Is there a way to modify my very simple form script to add/process an attachment without uploading to the server or using a library or mime?

```
$myemail = "google@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['letter'];
$subject= "FROM SITE!";
$message = "
Name: $name
E-mail: $email
Subject: $subject
Message:
$message";

mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
```

Comment: the hard way, as using phmailer or swiftmailer, while breaching your  requirements is the easy (standard) way

Comment: @Dagon that doesn't even make sense. Is it hard or easy? :P

Comment: yes, @Mike, yes it is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**No** unfortunately there is no simple way to do this. First of all you'll HAVE to find a way to upload the file to the server, otherwise your PHP script will not to able to access a file (on your desktop).

If you really want to avoid server side programming, you may want to consider a javascript /hosted solution like [FilePicker.io](https://www.inkfilepicker.com/) that let's you upload files from your desktop without server-side code, but this still wont' solve your email problem.